# SSL on multiple directories

Tags: php, apache, security, https, virtualhost

I have a website that is http, but has a port set up for https for a specific directory that is for the shopping cart. Now I'd like to use our SSL on a different directory in the same site as well. How can I go about configuring that?

I have tried looking into all of the config files as well as [the docs](http://www.modssl.org/docs/) and cannot figure it out.

I tried setting this in httpd.config as well

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:[ssl port]>   #also tried *:[ssl port] and [actual IP]:[ssl port]
    ServerAdmin shred@me.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/path/sslNeededDir"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

hoping that it would cause pages in this directory to use ssl port and become https, but that didn't do anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:** This finally got migrated over. I'm still looking for a solid answer on this. If anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using as the ssl port number?

Comment: The default 443

Comment: Check in `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` for SSL specific configuration if you are using Apache.  When creating an SSL virtual host, there are some special configuration directives that you must set in order for SSL to work.  What you have won't actually use SSL.

Comment: After you made changes did you restart apache? What does your VirtualHost setup for your non-secure section of the site look like?

Comment: @Shredder It may be that all you need to do is adjust the `DocumentRoot` in your SSL vhost/host.  Of course this may break existing links and stuff to your site so be aware of that, but SSL vhosts use a `DocumentRoot` just like regular vhosts.

Comment: @drew010 What I have in post I setup hoping it would cause requests to pages in the directory to use port 443 and make it ssl.

Comment: You will need to **either** adjust your docroot for the SSL vhost to one that is above both the directories that you want to serve (probably not the best idea) **or** add an `Alias` for the other directory you want to serve (better). Whatever you do, you will also need to create/adjust the appropriate `<Directory>` configurations so that everything you are trying to serve is permitted, and nothing else.

Comment: @Shredder  what Dave said...If you create a new vhost, then you need to go through all the settings for what ciphers are acceptable, which certificate to use (the cert is of course domain name specific) so you can't just create a new vhost and expect it to use the existing SSL config.  In my opinion, using an `Alias` like Dave said is the best way to go given your existing setup.

Comment: How would I go about setting up an Alias for this? Could you possibly provide an example in an answer for me?

Answer (score 1):

To do this with an alias is probably the simplest method. For argument's sake, lets say that this is your current `<VirtualHost>` for the directory that is served by SSL (known good config lifted off my dev server, if you're interested):

```
<VirtualHost 11.22.33.44:443>

  # Basic vhost config
  ServerAdmin administrator@mysite.com
  ServerName secure.mysite.com:443

  # Directory configuration
  DocumentRoot "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/htdocs"
  <Directory "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Logging configuration
  # Rem: ssl logging format defined in httpd.conf
  ErrorLog "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/logs/error.log"
  CustomLog "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/logs/access.log" ssl

  # SSL configuration
  # Rem: This works properly, fingerpoken ist verboten!
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/apache/conf/certs/secure-mysite-com.cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/apache/conf/certs/secure-mysite-com.key"
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory "/var/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

As you can (hopefully) see from the above config, when I request the root of the virtual host - i.e. I request `https://secure.mysite.com/` - I will be working with the local directory `/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/htdocs`.

As you can also hopefully see, setting up a virtual host properly is not just a trivial case of chucking a couple of `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` directives together, it needs to be carefully tuned to do exactly what you want it to. Most of the time you want host-specific logging, if you are using SSL you need to define some basic behaviours and make sure that information is available to your server side scripts, you need to do the obligatory buggering about writing IE specific code and configuration (grrr...) etc etc etc.

Now let's say I want to serve `/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.someothersite.com/htdocs` using the same certificate and host name. First I have to decide how I want to be able to access it - and I decide I want to use the address `https://secure.mysite.com/someothersite/`. I could just create a symlink in the original document root and have done with it, but that would be potentially confusing to other people working with the local file system. No, we'll use the aforementioned [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive instead.

The basic syntax for this is `Alias /url-path /full/file/system/path` - so I will need this line:

```
Alias /someothersite /WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.someothersite.com/htdocs
```

Note that I did *not* include the trailing slash on the end of either of the file paths. This is important for usage to be intuitive and behave as you expect. Great - now Apache will know that when I request `/someothersite`, I actually want to read a directory that isn't really in the document root. And you might think that's it, job done, but wait...

What about that `<Directory>` section? That only gives access permissions for the directory defined as `DocumentRoot`, so we'll need another section for our aliased directory. For the sake of argument, let's just copy/paste the original directory section and change the path it applies to:

```
<Directory "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.someothersite.com/htdocs">
  Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

*Now* it will work.

Let's have a look at our final configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 11.22.33.44:443>

  # Basic vhost config
  ServerAdmin administrator@mysite.com
  ServerName secure.mysite.com:443

  # Directory configuration
  DocumentRoot "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/htdocs"
  <Directory "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Alias for /someothersite virtual directory
  Alias /someothersite /WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.someothersite.com/htdocs
  <Directory "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.someothersite.com/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # Logging configuration
  # Rem: ssl logging format defined in httpd.conf
  ErrorLog "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/logs/error.log"
  CustomLog "/WebServer/virtualhosts/secure.mysite.com/logs/access.log" ssl

  # SSL configuration
  # Rem: This works properly, fingerpoken ist verboten!
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/apache/conf/certs/secure-mysite-com.cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/apache/conf/certs/secure-mysite-com.key"
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Directory "/var/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I want to set it up for a different directory in the same site. All pages in my cart directory are ssl, now I want to make another directory (in the same site/app root folder) ssl.

Comment: Well, how do you want to access them? You need some way to determine which directory the files are being requested from. What do your cart directory URLs look like? What do you want your other directories URL's to look like? You can't just have everything as one level URLs (not without a load of rewrite messing around anyway) - what if there are two files with the same name in the different directories? That is why alias is the simplest way, you just access your ither directory under `/alias`

Comment: My cart URLs are plain: `www.shop.com/cart/step1.php` - I need to make all pages in the `admin` folder ssl: `www.shop.com/admin/index.php` - The cart folder is the only place that is https. I thought there might have been some config for that cart folder and I could just add more config for the admin folder, but I can't find anything like that :/

Comment: Are you using `<VirtualHost>` anywhere currently or not? If you are, can you post the one that currently serves the SSL pages?

Comment: I don't understand because in httpd-ssl.config, it only points to the root (but the root is http; only /cart is https): 
`<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "D:/AppServ/www"
ServerName www.site.com:443` - I don't see `/cart` configured anywhere >_< Thanks for all your help BTW

Comment: so what happens if you try and go to `https://www.shop.com/admin/index.php`? What sort of a response do you get? 404? It's such a long time since I've set this up from scratch and I have always just deleted the default virtual host because I have been using explicit ones in `httpd-vhost.conf`

Comment: Hmm, nope, it actually goes to `https://www.shop.com/admin/index.php` and works. Interesting.. Both `http` and `https` seem to work o.O I was just trying `www.shop.com/admin` and it was automatically doing `http`

Comment: @Shredder It will do because when you just type an address into the browser it is assumed to be HTTP. It sounds as if your entire site will work in HTTPS, the only thing you need to do is change any links in your app so they point to HTTPS instead of HTTP :-D

Comment: When i try https anywhere else, it goes right back to http haha XD

Comment: Interesting - do you have any mod_rewrite rules anywhere?

Comment: I don't see any in httpd.config

Comment: Okay, its production and a company website so I can't, but its ok; Thanks a bunch for all your help!